# What is the most effective data structure for dynamically adding and removing JPanels from a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a GUI program in Java that creates dummy payroll records in a CSV file, using a set of home-cooked regular expressions that translate into pseudo-random data.

my program will be be a vertical list as such, where [] are text fields

[number of records]

1) [field descriptor]  [field data]

2) [field descriptor]  [field data]

3) [field descriptor]  [field data]

...

When the user hits "run", the program will generate a csv file, where the header will be populated with the field descriptors, and will generate  records with randomized data based on regular expressions inside of the field data, for testing.

my primary issue is that not all time and attendance systems deliver the same number of fields, let alone the same kinds of fields. So, in order to be able to properly emulate these systems, I need to allow the user to add extra panels that contain text fields for the field descriptor, and field data, or remove these panels.

What I know is that I need to keep some sort of dynamically managed list of these panels. My initial idea was to create a class that extends JPanel, and just add pointers for previous, next, and root.

Can I just extend a class like this and expect the parent JFrame to implement it properly as a child container?

Comment: Why not use: A) A `JTable` that allows you to add / edit / remove data. B) A. `JList` and have a separate `JDialog` that provides the GUI to input data into the program and updates the `JList`?

Comment: Use a `JTable`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: look at https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring00/V22.0480-005/lectures/lecture18/lecture18.htm and http://www.chka.de/swing/table/columns.html and http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/editable-jtable-example

Comment: OK!  I've been trying to wrap my brain around this one for a while. It's always great to have this connection to more experienced people who know more about the libraries and language.  The folks at the office are going to love me for this. Thank you!